# 404 when using a variable in URL- error: No query results for model [App\Models\Seeker]

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5

Im calling from the angular front side to my laravel back end.
When I use a variable in the url (USERID) it gives me a 404 error.

When I remove the USERID from the url it works and reach the function in the server.

Client side:

```
  getSeeker(userID: number) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.endPoint}/${userID}/getSeekerProfile`, 
      {headers: this.getTokenHeaders()})
  }
```

Server side:

```
    Route::get('candidate/{userID}/getSeekerProfile',   'CandidateController@getSeekerProfile');
```

Error on client side:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/api/headhunter/candidate/363/getSeekerProfile 404 (Not Found)
```

Error on server side:

```
message: "No query results for model [App\Models\Seeker]."
```

the targted function (getSeekerProfile):
PS - i also tried to just return dd('reached') and removing the (User $userID) parameter.

```
    public function getSeekerProfile(User $userID)
    {
        dd($userID);
    }
```

I cant really find the problem. Im not even using the Seeker model in relation to this piece of code.

Any ideas will be most welcome.

Thanks.

PS - maybe this will help:
There is a middle ware before the route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'headhunter','middleware' => ['AuthHeadhunter']], function () {
```

and it doesnt even go inside it.
is it possible that during the request it goes through another place first?

Comment: remove the Model injection for further debug: `public function getSeekerProfile($userID)` did you check your database for the user with id 363 and not having soft delete and `deleted_at` null

Comment: I think the problem is in your parameter of function "getSeekerProfile(User $userID)" in your controller. You are giving type of $userID as object of User model but it is just an integer from variable segment of URL. Please try removing User(type hint) before $userID, well if you want it to be type hinted make it "int". Hope it would helpful to you otherwise it seems good.

Comment: @Mubashar that's how laravel works, if you provide the ID (int) in the route and expect a model, it will launch `Model::find($id)` to get the instance of the model and inject it to the method. wich will return a 404 if the model is not present in the DB

Comment: I checked, user 363 exist, no soft delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so whoever is interested -> the answer has been found!
I had two routes one after the other:

```
Route::get('candidate/{seeker}/{jobID}','CandidateController@show');
Route::get('candidate/{userID}/getSeekerProfile','CandidateController@getSeekerProfile');
```

**The problem was the order of the routing**.
the request always entered the first router because in theory the first route has two variables (seeker & jobID) so potentially they could be anything:

```
Route::get('candidate/{can be anything}/{can be anything}','CandidateController@show');
```

so laravel looked at the first url (with the two variable) as equal to the second route:

```
get('candidate/{can be anything}/{can be anything}','CandidateController@show');

is the same as:

get('candidate/{can be anything}/getSeekerProfile','CandidateController@getSeekerProfile');
```

**Only if we enter the two variable route first**
so it enter the first route (which was incorrect)
the solution was to switch their order:

```
Route::get('candidate/{userID}/getSeekerProfile','CandidateController@getSeekerProfile');
Route::get('candidate/{seeker}/{jobID}','CandidateController@show');
```

now laravel will not get confused cause the "getSeekerProfile" is not a variable so it will know to enter inside.

In my initial post I only showed one route, cause I didnt even consider this as the problem.
Thank you for everyone who tried to help, and sorry for the initial unintended lack of information.

Answer (score 1):

public function getSeekerProfile(User $userID) this line send query for $userID to User Model.But User Model has not this $userID =>363
So you can saved this Id User Model or you can use

```
getSeekerProfile($userID)
{
$user = User::find($userID);
}
```

instead of

```
getSeekerProfile(User $userID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried that
```
    public function getSeekerProfile($userID)
    {
        dd($userID);
    }
```

still the same 
```
No query results for model [App\Models\Seeker]
```

Why is it still referring the the Seeker Model?

what weird is that the request doesnt even reach the AuthToken function that is in the middleware before the URL, and directly gives a 404

Comment: you can share dd result

Comment: it doenst reach the dd but gives the No query result found

Comment: User Model has not $userID on database. is not it

Comment: the user 363 does exist in the database in the User model

Comment: also i tried
getSeekerProfile($userID)
{ 
dd('reached')
}

still same error

Comment: AuthHeadhunter middleware can you share

Comment: it doesnt even reach there.
does laravel has a special handle for variables that are been send through url?

Comment: what is the endpoint angular side.this endpoint is can try in postman

Comment: the endpoint is good cause when i remove the userID

  getSeeker(userID: number) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.endPoint}/getSeekerProfile`, 
      {headers: this.getTokenHeaders()})
  }


    Route::get('candidate/getSeekerProfile',   'CandidateController@getSeekerProfile');



it does reach.